# Let $X$ be any set and $M=\{\emptyset, X\}$. Prove that the class of measurable functions are exactly those functions that are constant on X.

Tags: measure-theory, functions

I am attempting to solve a suggested problem while studying for my upcoming real analysis exam. Could somebody please help me with this question?

Question: Let $X$ be any set and $M=\{\emptyset , X\}$. Prove that the class of measurable functions are exactly those functions that are constant on $X$.

I think I have figured out how to prove that the constant function is measurable but I cannot figure out how to prove that no other functions are measurable.

Proving that constant function is measurable: If $f(x) = c$ for all $x\in X$, then $f^{-1}(V)=X$ if $c$ is an element of $V$ or empty set if $c$ is not an element of $V$. Since $M=\{\emptyset , X\}$, $f(x)=c$ is measurable.

How would I prove that all other functions are not measurable?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a measurable function. Pick any $x_0 \in X$. The set 
$$ E = \{x \in X : f(x) \not= f(x_0) \} = \{x \in X : f(x) > f(x_0) \} \cup \{x \in X : f(x) < f(x_0)\}$$
is measurable so it belongs to $\cal M$. That is, $E = \emptyset$ or $E = X$. But $x_0 \notin E$ so $E \not= X$. Thus $E = \emptyset$. It follows that $f(x) = f(x_0)$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: It's a good answer, but maybe overly complicated. Why don't you just define $E=\{x\in X: f(x)=f(x_0)\}$? Then $E$ is measurable and non-empty, so $E=X$.